# MeanJS : MissingSchemaError when runnig server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new in MEANJS : I am building a todolist with meanJS technology. I begin with server side. When i run my server.js file i got the following error :

```
node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:395
      throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
      ^
 MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Todo".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at Mongoose.model (D:\meanjs\todolist\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:395:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\meanjs\todolist\server\api\todo.js:5:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\meanjs\todolist\server\api\index.js:3:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

Here is my server.js file :

```
//Import dependencies
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


//Connect to mongoDB server
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/todoApp');
mongoose.set('debug', true);

//Get our API routes
const api = require('./server/api/');
//Require the models
require('./server/models/task.model'); //HERE
require('./server/models/todo.model'); //HERE

//Init express
const app = express();

//Set API routes
app.use('/api', api);

//Enable bodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

//Enable CORS
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
 next();
});

//Get environment port or use 3000
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

//Create HTTP server.
const server = http.createServer(app);

//Listen on port
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

I have threefiles in server/api project directory.
index.js

```
var router = require('express').Router();

router.use('/todo', require('./todo'));
router.use('/todo/task', require('./task'));

module.exports = router;
```

task.js

```
"use strict";
const router = require('express').Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Todo = mongoose.model('Todo');
const Task = mongoose.model('Task');

router.param('task', function (req, res, next, id) {
   if (!id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
       return res.sendStatus(422);
   }
   Task.findById(id).then((task) => {
       if (!task) { return res.sendStatus(404); }
       req.task = task;
       return next();
   })
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
   if (!req.body.todoId || !req.body.content) {
       res.sendStatus(422);
   }

   if (!req.body.todoId.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
       res.sendStatus(422);
   }

   Todo.findById(req.body.todoId).then((todo) => {
       if (!todo) { res.statusCode(404); }

       let task = new Task();
       task.content = req.body.content;
       task.state = false;
       task.todo = todo;

       task.save().then(() => {
           todo.tasks.push(task);
           todo.save().then(() => {
               res.json(task.toDto()).statusCode(201);
           });
       });
   });
});

router.put('/', (req, res) => {

   if (req.body.state == undefined || !req.body.id) {
       res.sendStatus(422);
   }

   if (!req.body.id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
       res.sendStatus(422);
   }


   Task.findById(req.body.id).then((task) => {
       task.state = req.body.state;
       task.save().then(() => {
           res.json(task.toDto()).statusCode(200);
       })
   })
});

router.delete('/:task', (req, res) => {
   let task = req.task;
   task.remove().then(() => {
       res.sendStatus(200);
   });
});
```

todo.js

```
"use strict";
const router = require('express').Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Todo = mongoose.model('Todo');
const Task = mongoose.model('Task');

router.param('todo', function (req, res, next, id) {

   if (!id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
       return res.sendStatus(422);
   }

   Todo.findById(id)
       .populate('tasks')
       .then(function (todo) {
           if (!todo) { return res.sendStatus(404); }

           req.todo = todo;

           return next();
       });
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {

   Todo.find()
       .populate('tasks')
       .then((todos) => {
           if (!todos) { return res.sendStatus(404); }

           return res.json({
               todos: todos.map((todo) => {
                   return todo.toDto();
               })
           }).statusCode(200);
       });
});


router.post('/', (req, res) => {
   if (!req.body.title) {
       res.sendStatus(422);
   }

   let todo = new Todo();
   todo.title = req.body.title;

   todo.save().then(() => {
       res.json(todo.toDto()).statusCode(201);
   })

});

router.delete('/:todo', (req, res) => {

   req.todo.remove().then(function () {
       return res.sendStatus(200);
   });
});
```

I have in server/models two file defining each model.
todo.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Task = mongoose.model('Task','TaskSchema');

let TodoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   title: { type: String, required: [true, "can't be blank"], index: true },
   tasks: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Task' }]
}, { timestamps: true });

TodoSchema.pre('remove', (next) => {
   Task.remove({ todoId: this._id }).exec();
   next();
})

TodoSchema.methods.toDto = function () {

   return {
       id: this._id,
       title: this.title,
       tasks: this.tasks.map((task) => {
           return task.toDto();
       })
   }

}

mongoose.model('Todo', TodoSchema);
```

task.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let TaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   content: { type: String, maxlength: 200 },
   state: { type: Boolean, default: false },
   todo: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Todo' }
}, { timestamps: true });


TaskSchema.methods.toDto = function () {
   return {
       id: this._id,
       content: this.content,
       state: this.state
   }
};

mongoose.model('Task', TaskSchema);
```

Where am i wrong please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in server.js

```
//Get our API routes
const api = require('./server/api/');
//Require the models
require('./server/models/task.model'); //HERE
require('./server/models/todo.model'); //HERE
```

change the order

```
//Require the models
require('./server/models/task.model'); //HERE
require('./server/models/todo.model'); //HERE
//Get our API routes
const api = require('./server/api/');
```

Comment: mark this as solved then open another Question. you can't chain another question here. (problems should be solved at once for future reference)

Answer (score 0):

In your Schema files ( task.model.js && todo.model.js ), you are not exporting the models.  In both files, you need to add the following:

```
// models/todo.model.js
module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', TodoSchema);

// models/task.model.js
module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', TaskSchema);
```

Remove the extraneous requires in your server.js:

```
require('./server/models/task.model'); // GET RID OF THIS
require('./server/models/todo.model'); // GET RID OF THIS
```

Also in todo.js and task.js, since you are now exporting the models, you must import the models like so:

```
const Todo = require('../models/task.model')
const Task = require('../models/todo.model')
```

Note: This is assuming that I have your directory structure correct.

```
-server
    -api
    -models
```

Comment: How is everything going now? Are you getting a new/different error?

Comment: Also, in your todo.model file, the task model import is wrong.  Change that to: `const Task = require('./task.model')`